# Kubuntu 20.04 "Desktop effects were restarted due to a graphics reset"

Tags: drivers, graphics

Every time I suspend my Kubuntu 20.04 (Plasma 5.18.5) install, upin waking it back up, all of the desktop icons appear with garbled black & white bars instead of text labels, and some of the systray icons appear as solid white boxes.  There will be a notification saying "Desktop effects were restarted due to a graphics reset," and the display is glitchy.  Logging out & back in fixes it - until the next time I suspend.

After a bit of googling, I understand that this is most likely due to graphics driver issues.  I had previously setup my graphics drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Now, `ubuntu-drivers devices` gives:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000174Dsv00001028sd00000816bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce MX130]
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d000024FDsv00008086sd00000050bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless 8265 / 8275
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

Any advice on how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated. I've only been running Linux for a few weeks, but have had endless reliability issues related to graphics - significantly more than over the decades of running Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  Just explicitly uninstall the crappy proprietary nvidia drivers, and let it fallback on the built-in open-source nouveau ones:

```
 sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-440
```

After that...no more issues & restoring from sleep always works properly.